# Can't install gloobus-preview Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: package-management, 13.10, software-installation, gloobus-preview

I was trying to install gloobus-preview following this site: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/08/install-gloobus-preview-in-ubuntu-13-04/

The problem is that when I try to install the packages - gloobus-preview and gloobus-sushi - the Terminal writes that the packages where not found, although it found the repository.
I'm running Ubuntu 13.10.
What do I have to do?

Answer (score 1):

The link above clearly says that

> Gloobus Preview is available for Ubuntu 13.04, Ubuntu 12.04, Ubuntu 12.10, and Ubuntu 11.10 **from the PPA repository.**

It was not available for Ubuntu 13.10. So that `package not found` error comes.

Answer (score 1):

The PPA is not available for Saucy yet. If you want a preview function than you can try installing `gnome-sushi`

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-sushi
```

Now restart Nautilus

```
nautilus -q
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that [this](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/04/gloobus-preview-update-brings-gtk3-and.html) article talks about that

Try this

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gloobus-dev/gloobus-preview
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gloobus-preview gloobus-sushi
```